# Ensure PHP shutdown function is called

Tags: php, exception, callback, shutdown

I'm trying to catch as many errors as possible in PHP and properly handle them in a non-default way. My question is best illustrated in this example:

```
<?php 

function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    echo "Error handler here <br>\n";
    //throw new Exception($errstr);
}
function shutdownFunction() {
    echo "Hi I'm in here <br>\n";
}

set_error_handler("errorHandler");
register_shutdown_function("shutdownFunction");

try {
    $undefined->ok(); // causes some error
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Caught the exception <br>\n";
}
```

The result of running this code as a PHP program will indicate that `errorHandler()` is run, a PHP error is printed (if "display_errors" is set to "On"), and then `shutdownFunction()` is run.

The problem I'm having arises if I uncomment out that exception throw; I want to throw exceptions on PHP errors as often as possible. If I uncomment the `throw` statement out, then the error handler is called, which throws an exception thus causing a further error which results in `shutdownFunction()` not to be called.

It is my understanding that I can't make this error into a catchable exception; however, I would at least like to ensure that the shutdown function is called without restricting my ability to catch at least *some* php errors as exceptions (meaning I don't want to remove that `throw` statement in `errorHandler()`).

Is there some check in the errorHandler that I can do to check whether or not throwing it will cause `shutdownFunction()` to be bypassed?

Comment: Interesting; the only time this didn't work for me is when a fatal error is generated, but the custom error handler doesn't catch that anyway (from http://php.net/set_error_handler:  "The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called.").

Comment: In the code example you provided, compare what happens when you try `$undefined->ok();` vs. `$test = $undefined`.  When I test with the latter, the shutdown function still fires, even if the error handler throws an exception.  When I test with the former, neither the error handler nor the shutdown function fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I'm solving this is to check if the $errstr parameter starts with "Undefined variable" - and if it does, then I'm not throwing the exception. I suppose if there are any other errors that have a similar issue, i'll do the same thing with those. I can't find a comprehensive list of php errors and what their affects are though, so it'll have to be ad hoc

Answer (score 2):

Throw an exception from the error handler, then use [set_exception_handler](http://set_exception_handler) to handle uncaught exceptions.